# Kendo Grid Date Column Does not show real date

Tags: kendo-ui

My kendo grid is showing date like this /Date(691869600000)/ . How do i solve this?

Answer (score 7):

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date/2316066#2316066) I got the Steve code to work for my case. Try this template:

```
"#= kendo.toString(new Date(parseInt(myField.substr(6))),'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt')#"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
'#= kendo.toString(yourDateField,"MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM tt")#'
```

and make your field type as `date`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the date as a type in your datasource definition - else it will just be a string:

For example if your field is birthday:

```
var kendoDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
schema: { 
 model: {
 fields: {
  birthday: { type: "date"}
 }
 }           
});
```

And when you define the Grid:

```
kendoGrid({
 selectable: whatever values..etc
 columns: your-response,
 dataSource: kendoDS 
});
```

See this for more info: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/framework/data-source/json-date-handling-changed-in-latest-release.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use [template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#columnstemplate-string) like the following or like the one in the documentation link.

```
#= kendo.format("{0:d}",theDateTimeFieldName)#
```

Answer (score 0):

var  offsetMiliseconds = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

```
    #= kendo.toString(new Date( parseInt(JSONDateTime.substr(6)) + offsetMiliseconds),"dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm tt") #
```